# Web Scraping table with Python is just returning an empty list back

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape all the data from this table, using Python-Beautifulsoup, from all the pages for this website and into a dictionary, as seen from the code below. However, this is just returning an empty list back

Moreover, I am also trying to scrape for each company which has it’s own separate page,into that dictionary also.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
from pprint import pprint

case_data = []

case_url = 'https://www.dataquest.io'
case_page = requests.get(case_url) 
soup_case = BeautifulSoup(case_page.content, 'html.parser') 
case_table = soup_case.find('div',{'class':'slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-max-medium-table_stacked cCaseList'})

pprint(case_table)
```

Comment: Print case_page.content to check if you are getting HTML than look for scrapping issue

Comment: 1. Full html is not being fetched. 2. Use 'table' instead of 'div' attribute.

Comment: @VikasSharma I have printed case_page.content, it looks like the table data is not present there

Comment: Print case_page only and check it it has 200 repsonse, if not you need to provide headers in requests.get

Comment: @ShwetaChandel I thought that is was full HTML? If not, may I ask how is it obtained

Comment: That page is loaded dynamically using jscript so requests can't handle it; try selenium or requests-html.

Comment: @User112211 are you trying to edit the link on my answer ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Yes, as I need to update the link for various reasons. Your answer works great, please can you allow for the edit, so I can tick your answer

Comment: @User112211 I've masked it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
import pandas as pd

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://masked_per_user_request/")
time.sleep(2)

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]

df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False)

driver.quit()
```

Output: [click here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/d864571557c70a75a8b39c0a648e56d3/result.csv)

Note that the data is rendered via `XHR` request from `JSON` back-end whcih is [XHR-URL](https://askrspo.force.com/Complaint/s/sfsites/aura?r=1&other.ComplaintsCase.searchCaseList=1&ui-communities-components-aura-components-forceCommunity-controller.Headline.getInitData=1&ui-communities-components-aura-components-forceCommunity-richText.RichText.getParsedRichTextValue=1) So you might be able to call it via `POST` request including `JSON` body data and `Cookies`

Something like the following:

```
import requests


data = {
    'message': '{"actions":[{"id":"108;a","descriptor":"serviceComponent://ui.communities.components.aura.components.forceCommunity.richText.RichTextController/ACTION$getParsedRichTextValue","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"html":"<p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">The RSPO aspires to ensure transparency throughout the complaints process and the reporting thereof. Decisions not to disclose information through the RSPO website require motivation on genuine grounds that disclosure will go against the interest of the complaints process and/or may jeopardize the well-being or safety of stakeholders involved, and that non-disclosure does not undermine adherence to the principles and objectives of RSPO:</span></p><p><br></p><ul><li style=\"text-align: justify;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">The non-disclosed information relates to a legitimate aim, i.e. peaceful and constructive resolution of complaints in accordance with RSPO objectives and P&amp;C;</span></li></ul><p><br></p><ul><li style=\"text-align: justify;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">The disclosure of said information threatens harm to that aim; and</span></li></ul><p style=\"text-align: justify;\"><br></p><ul><li style=\"text-align: justify;\"><span style=\"font-size: 14px;\">The harm to the aim is greater than the public interest in having the information disclosed.</span></li></ul><p>&nbsp;</p>"},"version":"47.0","storable":true},{"id":"88;a","descriptor":"apex://ComplaintsCaseController/ACTION$searchCaseList","callingDescriptor":"markup://c:CaseList","params":{"searchString":"","pageNumber":1,"defaultPageSize":"10"}},{"id":"111;a","descriptor":"serviceComponent://ui.communities.components.aura.components.forceCommunity.controller.HeadlineController/ACTION$getInitData","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"uniqueNameOrId":"","pageType":""},"version":"47.0","storable":true}]}',
    'aura.context': '{"mode":"PROD","fwuid":"5fuxCiO1mNHGdvJphU5ELQ","app":"siteforce:communityApp","loaded":{"APPLICATION@markup://siteforce:communityApp":"0luQG4JZE_TU28tAfQgGSA"},"dn":[],"globals":{},"uad":false}',
    'aura.pageURI': '/Complaint/s/casetracker',
    'aura.token': 'undefined'
}

r = requests.post("https://masked_per_user_request/", json=data).json()


print(r)
```

> You will need to figure out the Cookies Parameters.